# Combine filtered data from each files into new data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I want to filter specific line of data from multiple files and combine it into one data frame, thus that data frame should be growing each time it read new file. My code here able to loop through all the files but only create data frame of the last file. can I get my desired data frame without have to combine all-raw-bulky data from each files first?. Pls advice.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
y = 1978
N <- 10
for (i in 1:N) {
  yr = y +(as.numeric(i))
  yr = as.character(yr)
  p <- paste0("c:/Users/Hp/Documents/",yr,".csv")

  #read.csv
  dat <- read.csv(p,header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F)
  #filter
  dat_sub <- filter(dat, hght_m > 0)
  dat_sub <- filter(dat_sub, temp_c > 0)
  dat1_sub <- filter(dat_sub, pres_hpa == 1000)
  dat2_sub <- filter(dat_sub, pres_hpa == 925)
  dat3_sub <- filter(dat_sub, pres_hpa == 850)
  dat4_sub <- filter(dat_sub, pres_hpa == 700)
}
all.temp <- rbind(dat1_sub,dat2_sub, dat3_sub,dat4_sub)
ggplot(data = all.temp, aes(x= as.Date(date), y = temp_c, group = pres_hpa, color = pres_hpa)) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the `rbind` inside the loop, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

y = 1978
N <- 10
all.temp <- NULL

for (i in 1:N) {
  yr = y +(as.numeric(i))
  yr = as.character(yr)
  p <- paste0("c:/Users/Hp/Documents/",yr,".csv")

  #read.csv
  dat <- read.csv(p,header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F)
  #filter
  dat_sub <- filter(dat, hght_m > 0)
  dat_sub <- filter(dat_sub, temp_c > 0)
  dat1_sub <- filter(dat_sub, pres_hpa == 1000)
  dat2_sub <- filter(dat_sub, pres_hpa == 925)
  dat3_sub <- filter(dat_sub, pres_hpa == 850)
  dat4_sub <- filter(dat_sub, pres_hpa == 700)

  all.temp <- rbind(all.temp, dat1_sub, dat2_sub, dat3_sub, dat4_sub)
}

ggplot(data = all.temp, aes(x= as.Date(date), y = temp_c, group = pres_hpa, color = pres_hpa)) + geom_line()
```